# can qtip show the value of the currently hovered element

Tags: jquery, qtip2

I want to use the qtip jquery plug-in to display the complete value of the hovered element.

The reason is the the input field is too short to show the entire string so I want to show it on hover.

When I try my code, the qtip "box" displays, but there is no content.

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="desc" value="this is a long string of text that doesn't all show on the page">
```

CSS

```
.desc{
  width:80px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$('.desc').qtip({
  content: {
    text: function(event, api) {
      $(this).val();
    }
  }
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bpy84f7p/)

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to "return" the value

```
$('.desc').qtip({
  content: {
    text: function(event, api) {
      return $(this).val();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: ... which is mentioned in [the documentation](http://qtip2.com/options#content.text): *You can also specify a function that returns the content...*